# Add web component to the DOM

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I created my dart web component that extends a DIV element.
In DART I can add a DIV element to the DOM with:

```dart
DivElement div = new DivElement();
document.body.elements.add(div);
```

[Dart html api](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/DivElement.html)

Can I do the same thing with my web component?
What's the right syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Web UI Specification has a section about web component instantiation:

http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/spec.html#instantiation

> ... call new FooComponent.forElement(elem) in Dart. We don’t recommend
>   using this approach because this constructor call cannot be used by
>   itself–it requires several set up steps. We might have runtime
>   libraries to make this easier in the future ...